# Any easy way to test Ember loading substates?

Tags: ember.js, routes

Is there a easy way in the route so I can test loading substates in Ember 2

I have tried this but it doesn't work. In the originating route, I have:

```
  actions: {
    willTransition(transition) {
      this.sleep(5000);
    }
  },
  sleep(time) {
    return new RSVP.Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To see loading substate,

```
model() {
        return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Ember.run.later(() => {
                resolve("failed to load application model");
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

To see error loading substate,

```
model() {
        return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Ember.run.later(() => {
                reject(
                    new Error('failed to load application model')
                );
            }, 500);
        });
    }
```

You should have corresponding hbs file to show. refer ember official guide. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Comment: The loading route can even more easily accessed by just entering it's URL. There is an actual URL registered to every loading route.

Comment: I haven't done any testing in ember...i thought OP want to manual wait for some time to see/view loading state.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. You don't have to code to access the loading state, you can just enter the URL to see it :)

Comment: Got you ..To access loading or error state, need to put entry in `router.js` like `this.route('application-error');` ..then we can access it directly through URL `/application-error`..  thats what you mean it Am i right?. thanks for the hint @lawitschka

Comment: The loading route is auto-generated by Ember, just like the index route for example.

`this.route('app', function() {
  this.route('dashboard');
});
`

generates automatically the route `app.loading` and that can be access via URL `/app/loading`. That's what I meant. For error routes, you may have to create them specifically in `router.js`. Sorry for the broken markup